# SQL Query loop in Postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, loops

I have DB in Postgresql 12 and PgAdmin 4 and a lot of queries like:

```
update public.register set address = replace(address,'Á','A') where address like '%Á%';
update public.register set address = replace(address,'Â','A') where address like '%Â%';
update public.register set address = replace(address,'Ã','A') where address like '%Ã%';
update public.register set address = replace(address,'Ä','A') where address like '%Ä%';
update public.register set address = replace(address,'Å','A') where address like '%Å%';
```

I want to declare arrays like this:

```
SET array1 = ARRAY['Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å]
SET array2 = ARRAY['A','A','A','A','A']
```

and make a loop just like:

```
for(i=0; i<count(array1[]); i++){
update public.register set address = replace(address,array1[i],array2[i]) where address like '%array1[i]%'; 
}
```

I have not found any good and working idea on forums.

Thanks for any info about this :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop. This can be done using a single UPDATE statement using `regexp_replace()`

```
update register 
  set address = regexp_replace(address, '[ÁÂÃÄÅ]', 'A', 'g') 
where address ~ '[ÁÂÃÄÅ]';
```

`'[ÁÂÃÄÅ]'` matches each character in the list. The `'g'` option will replace all occurrences in the value.

The WHERE clause then makes sure that only those rows that contain these characters in the `address` column are changed.

It would work without the WHERE as well, as the `regexp_replace()` will not change the address if the characters aren't contained. But it's good coding practice to only update those rows that do actually change.

---

Another option is to install the [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) extension, then you can use:

```
update register 
  set address = unaccent(address) 
where address <> unaccent(address);
```

This has the additional benefit, that you can use language specific rules if you want.